# Is it possible to communicate two local git-repos?

Tags: git

I got a very strange scenario today at work involving git repos. The idea is to have two repositories with the following constrains

**local-RepoA**

1. has all my source code, say, `ShareOk.cpp` and `ShareNok.cpp`
2. pushes to http://remote-RepoA.git

**local-RepoB**

1. should only have those files from **RepoA** which are fine to share with other people, in this case only `ShareOk.cpp`
2. before pushing changes to remote, needs to do some code cleaning
3. pushes to http://remote-RepoB.git

Is there a way to "push" certain files from `local-RepoA` to `local-RepoB` to do code cleaning and then push the changes to `remote-RepoB` ?

This does not make sense to me, but I was asked to check for some way to link the two local repos.

**EDIT**

From the answer provided below, I think my description was not complete so I will extend it further

There are two developement groups.

**Group A** possess all the source code and work only in **repoA** whose upstream is set to `http://repoA.git`. All the source code could be messy and with untested code.

**Group A** wants to give **Group B** the code up to a certain point/commit from **repoA** that is known to be working flawlessly, with clean and tested code. So **Group A** wants to have a way to put into **repoB** with upstream `http://repoB.git` this code preserving the history of changes for the files being shared with **Group B**.

Finally **Group B** just clones/pulls from `http://repoB.git` and check the code compiles and runs and then they do some other stuff with it.

Comment: What I believe you need here is multiple remote's configured and explicitly specify the remote to which you want to push your changes to. More info: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Maybe you can solve it using hard/soft links?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that pushing commits/files from one repo to another is really what you want. From the provided context I cannot decide if this would apply, but generally I would recommend to have Repo B be your upstream (main) repo and work on that (publicly), like you would do with any package or module you want to share.

In RepoA you can setup RepoB as a dependency, and apply any customizations or modifications by extending RepoB, while only committing overrides in RepoA.

This would also prevent you having to 'censor' files or commits you want to push publicly.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I guess something was not clear in my question. So I will edit it, but I believe what you suggest is more or less what I might need. When you say "in repoA set repoB as dependency" how do I do that?

Comment: This is very specific to your coding language of choice, and any frameworks you might use. I'd recommend to do some research on package management/dependency management for your specific language. Ruby has gems, NodeJS has NPM, PHP has Composer etc... If you're still stuck, getting this specific question answered for your situation is just one SO post away :).

Answer (score 1):

> Group A wants to give Group B the code up to a certain point/commit from repoA that is known to be working flawlessly, with clean and tested code. So Group A wants to have a way to put into repoB with upstream http://repoB.git this code preserving the history of changes for the files being shared with Group B.

It sounds like repoB should be a bare clone of repoA. Then you just need to manage the process of pulling B from A.

Assuming some release branch, or a tag indicating what commit in A is the "known good" point B should follow, you just need to run `git pull KnownGoodPoint:master` while in the repoB directory.

This also assumes no-one in group B is pushing back to repoB, so you should disallow that.

Comment: I am a little bit lost in the process since I never used bare clone before. Could you develop a bit more the process probably with commands?

Comment: I did a `git clone --bare http//repoA.git` which created a `C:\repoA.git` directory. Suppose I then change to `C:\repoB` and I want to pull a "known good" point from repoA, do some code cleaning and finally do a push to `http://repoB.git`, where does the `git pull knownGood:master` comes into play?

Comment: Why did you create an intermediate repo? You can clone B directly from A on the server. Then, in that directory on the server, is where you can manage updating B from A.

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused, which is the intermediate repo?

Comment: You created `C:\repoA.git`. That isn't either of the repos (A & B) you wanted, so why create it?